# 'border-radius' issues in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I have a problem with "border-radius" in IE9 (I haven't tried in other IE's versions).

Image of the problem:
http://imageshack.us/a/img171/4060/ieproblem11.png

And how the same part looks on Chrome / Firefox / Android / etc.
http://imageshack.us/a/img837/3730/ieproblem12.png

The HTML part:

```html
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="console-background" style="float: right; width: 80px; font-size: 16px; padding: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px; border-bottom-right-radius: 10px; border-left: 1px solid #ffffff; border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold;">
        PC
    </div>
    <div class="gray-title" style="float: right; width: 579px; border-top-right-radius: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius: 0px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.console-background {
    background-color: #2599cf;
}

.gray-title {
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

What can be the problem? And how can I fix it?

Comment: I used your exact code in Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 and the border radius worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you have border-radius:10px; which is setting all of the corners to 10px. In the HTML, you have a style specified to the bottom and top right corners, which I believe is the look you want. Try changing your css to:

```
.gray-title
{
background-color: #efefef;
border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
padding: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px; 
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
color: #555555;
font-size: 14px;
}
```

If you already have an attached stylesheet, it would be cleaner to put it all in the .css file rather than doing it inside the html tags. That might be a personal preference but it would make it easier to read! :)